# Fastest way to copy the full path of a file and insert it into a script

Tags: windows, macos, path, ubuntu-12.04, shortcut

In many task I've to open a file with a script so I've to type the full path of the file. Usually I go to properties of the file and then I copy the path and then the name of the file. I wonder if there is a faster way to do that.
I would like to copy it in one click or drag the file in the IDE or something like that....

(I'm using Windows XP, Mac Mountain Lion and Ubuntu 12.04 sometimes).

Comment: You are already using the shortcutted method by using a gui called Windows :)

Comment: @Edward maybe is a shortcutted method but it seems very slow....:_)

Answer (score 0):

In windows pressing shift and right-click allows you to select copy path.

In Mac right click and pressing alt allows copying file as path.

I've found [Copy path](http://copypath.codeplex.com/) for Windows that:

> that will allow you to right click on a drive or file system object
> and copy the path of the file to the clipbpoard. If the drive is a
> mapped drive or the file system object exits on a mapped drive it will
> resolve the full UNC path.

On Windows Shift+Right Click allows you to copy the path directly.

Alternatively many shell (like the shells of Spyder and Canopy,Ipython) support a drag and drop option that allow you to drag the file inside the shell and get the path of the file.